# Is there a way to make searching function by URL with Online API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, function, web

Im using YTS API and I would like to make searching fucntion.
Is there a way on URL condition? like

```
 &search_condition=spider&
```

this is the link of YTS API
https://yts.am/api#list_movies

```
  fetch('https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=20')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to the [YTS API doc](https://yts.am/api) you can see on the List Movies the `Endpoint Parameters` which contain `query_term`. It might be what you are looking for.

So, the GET would be

```
fetch('https://yts.am/api/v2/list_movies.json?sort_by=download_count&limit=20&query_term=spider')
```